# Add folder name using slash in hosts file

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, hosts

I have drupal project as folder name is abc in `/var/www/html`.

In the hosts file, I have define domain name as

```
127.0.0.1    www.abc.com
```

In the settings.php of drupal project (`/var/www/html/abc/sites/default`),

```
$base_url = 'http://www.abc.xyz/abc'
```

The images soruce url is like `sites/default/files/1.png` and when page is loading it should be like as `www.abc.xyz/abc/sites/default/files/1.png` but it will be as `www.abc.xyz/sites/default/files/1.png`.

How can I add folder name so that image will load?

Comment: to which folder the domain name pointing to ?? and are you prefixing `$base_url`  in the image source URL ??

Comment: @SameerK Domain Name is pointing to the folder abc in /var/www/html/abc and the only domin name is prefixing in the image source url not $base_url